# Stripping Ubuntu 10.04 Server down to JeOS like setup?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud

I am setting up a web application to run on cloud servers that will be created and destroyed programmatically via a supplied API.  For my purposes I want a stripped down version of ubuntu like JeOS, to which I would be adding Node.js and some Node modules.  The server company offers the ability to create custom system images by taking an image of a running server but my initial server needs to be booted with a standard image, in this case an Ubuntu 10.04 LAMP image.  I would therefore need to strip out the unneeded packages.  What is the safe way to accomplish this?  Is there a list somewhere of what is included in JeOS or something similar so I can determine what is unsafe to remove?

Edit: I want to note that I have read similar questions where uses are trying to strip the server down for performance reasons, where the key is minimizing the number of running processes and memory usage.  In my situation I am looking to minimize the image size to reduce the time it takes to create a new server.

Comment: This question should be moved to askubuntu.com - unfortunatly, I don't get this option in the flag-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a project called [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net/), which will help you slick out any ubuntu image. As Ubuntu uses the APT-packet handler, you will be warned, if you try to remove something you shouldn't. If you e.g. try to remove bash via `apt-get remove bash`, you'll have to type in "Yes, do as I say!" instead of simply pressing "Y". ;)

Internally, this is done with the `essential`-flag of the dpkg-system, so you can't really destroy a system with that. I would suggest taking an ubuntu minimal image, stripping it down as far as possible, and then re-adding the services you need. If that is still too much for you (which may be possible, as the packages usually have huge dependencies not always needed), you could compile your own applications - and sacrificing automatic updates on those with it.